# PHP Get snd Post both set

Tags: php, html

loaded page from javascript. tested for GET & POST. Only GET set as expected;

```
window.location.href = "medications_edit_revised.html?recordId="+id ;
```

Retrieved and used the data from the GET[]

Reloaded page  from SUBMIT as shown below.

```
    <form method="post" action="">
<table id="detailsDivTable">
    <?php
$editClass->selectTheRecord();
    ?>
</table>
<fieldset name="Group1">
<legend>Group box</legend>
    <input name="saveButton" type="submit" value="Save" />
    <input name="deleteButton" type="submit" value="Delete" />
    <input name="cancelButton" type="submit" value="Cancel" />          
</fieldset>
</form>`
```

Tested GET[] & SET[]

```
    if  (isset($_GET['recordId']) ) {
    $recordId = $_GET['recordId'];
    require_once "medications_edit_revised.class.php";
    $editClass = new editRevisedClass($DBH, $recordId);
    }

    if(isset($_POST['saveButton'])) {
```

Both tested TRUE. Is this normal behavior. I expected the GET[] would have been cleared when the form was POSTed

If yes is there a way to clear the GET before sending the SUBMIT

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - You need to show us your code for us to be able to understand what it does and what you need to change. Otherwise, all answers and suggestions will be pure guesswork.

Comment: yes, it depends on the stitution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the URL like this:

```
window.location.href = "medications_edit_revised.html?recordId="+id ;
```

You have set URL params. Then when you do this:

> Reloaded page from SUBMIT as shown below.
>
> ```
> <form method="post" action="">
> ```

Because the `action` is empty it'll retain the URL parameters, because that's what empty and (eg) `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` do - they send to the current URL, params and all.

You already know the URL so just set it as needed:

```
action="medications_edit_revised.html"
```

Comment: thanks, that explains it. How do I mark your rply a answering my question? Frank

Comment: Glad to help. Just click the grey tick to make it green :)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing POST/GET requests and the PHP `$_POST` and `$_GET` superglobal variables.

PHP will populate `$_GET` with data in the query string of the URL the request was made to.

PHP will populate `$_POST` with data in the request body of a POST request if that data is encoded using a supported encoding.

It doesn't matter if the request was caused by JavaScript, a form submission, or something else.

> Is this normal behavior.

Yes

> If yes is there a way to clear the GET before sending the SUBMIT

Submit the form to a URL which does not have a query string.

The URL the form is submitted to will be specified by the `action` attribute.

If you don't have an `action` attribute, it will be submitted to the URL of the current page. If that URL has a query string, then so will be the URL that the form is submitted to (and thus `$_GET` will be populated).

If you want to avoid that, then specify the `action` explicitly.

Answer (score -2):

Can you please past some of your code?

If you use GET to revice your variable, it gets it from the URL: example.com?name=jesper&lastname=kaae

The differences is:

> GET requests a representation of the specified resource. Note that GET should not be used for operations that cause side-effects, such as using it for taking actions in web applications. One reason for this is that GET may be used arbitrarily by robots or crawlers, which should not need to consider the side effects that a request should cause.

And

> POST submits data to be processed (e.g., from an HTML form) to the identified resource. The data is included in the body of the request. This may result in the creation of a new resource or the updates of existing resources or both.

[You can read more about them here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the OP's question, though. It only explains the differences between GET and POST. As you self point out, the OP needs to share their code. Before that, no one can give the OP a proper answer.